# Are there any ways to write integration tests for Reactive Kafka in Spring?

Tags: apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

I need to write integration tests and mock reactive Kafka consumer. I see there're ways to do it with blocking Kafka, like using `@EmbeddedKafka` but was not able to find information about reactive

Comment: The broker isn't reactive, only your clients are, so why can you not use EmbeddedKafka (or testcontainers)?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the [existing tests](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/main/src/test/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/KafkaReceiverTest.java) for reactor-kafka

Answer (score 0):

As linked in the comments, `reactor-kafka` project themselves use [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) for integration tests. If you don't run tests in an environment with Docker, then `spring-kafka-test`'s `EmbeddedKafka`, or `junit-kafka` project should still work with Reactive-based Kafka clients since you really only need `bootstrap.servers` property to point at any valid broker server.

Regarding mocks, you don't need an actual broker; that's the point of mocking. Their [source code](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/tree/main/src/test/java/reactor/kafka/mock) does include mock classes, too.